# NG0900: Error trying to diff 'value' Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently having an issue with my API results. I'm fairly new to Programming so I don't understand why It's giving me an error.

I'm trying to display my product information on the HTML page of my Angular.ts project.

Here is my product-info.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ProductArticle } from '../models/product-article';
import { ProductArticleService } from '../services/product-article.service';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-info',
  templateUrl: './product-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-info.component.css']
})
export class ProductInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  products: ProductArticle[] = [];


  constructor(private productArticleService: ProductArticleService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  public getProductInfo() {
    this.productArticleService
      .getProduct()
      .subscribe((result: ProductArticle[]) => (this.products = result));
    console.log(this.products);
  }

}
```

And here is my product-info.component.html

```
<button (click)="getProductInfo()"></button>

<label *ngFor="let product of products">
    {{ product.id }}
</label>
```

Also this is the ProductArticle class.

```
export class ProductArticle {
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
}
```

The console.log returns me an Object, yet I can't display it using *ngFor. When searching for the issue I found similar problems but I can't seem to make it work.

Here is my console log. Since I filter the results in the API request I can't get an Array returned. But it seems I need an Array.

```
`{id: 3, name: 'Overdog', description: 'Pineapple', price: 3434}
description
: 
"Pineapple"
id
: 
3
name
: 
"Overdog"
price
: 
3434
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object`
```

So basically tried to show my Api results in my UI. I used *ngFor but only got an error
(Code: NG0900).

I also tried setting the 'products' array empty inside the method.

```
  public getProductInfo() {
    this.products = [];
    this.productArticleService
      .getProduct()
      .subscribe((result: ProductArticle[]) => (this.products = result));
    console.log(this.products);
  }
```

I got the same result.

Comment: Congrats! but if you found an answer to your question, please do not put it inside the question post! (that's where the question goes!). Please format it as a properly formatted answer to your question for the next person who comes looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error and the issue happened to be on the object that i was expecting.

So in my case from my BE api, i was getting a **Page<ProductArticle[]>** and the response object format that i was getting was like this:

```
"content": [
    **here was the array of Product Object**
]
```

while on the FE i was waiting for **ProductArticle[]**, so in this case i was getting the above error, i solve the issue like so:

on my service where i am sending the request
 `public getProduct(): Observable<**any**> { return this.http.get<**any**>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}`); }`

i changed the expected value to **any** instead of **ProductArticle[]**.

and in my ts file i had to do tho following:

`this.productArticleService .getProduct() .subscribe( (result: ProductArticle[])=> (this.products =` result.content`) );`

I had to call the **.content** on the response in order to get/access the array of values returned from response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `{id: 3, name: 'Overdog', description: 'Pineapple', price: 3434}`this is the products you're trying to iterating. Since this isn't an array you cant use it with ngFor. ngFor only accepts iterables such as Arrays. This is called Object and you can't iterate it.you should update the API response. Or if you want to use this object like Array, you can simply put it inside an array like this ( makes no sense though );
`this.products = [result]`

Also since you're fetching the data after you're clicking the button, you should check if there is anything called products in html before iterating it. Here is an example;

```
<ng-container *ngIf="products?.length">
// do your iteration here with ngFor
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should push to your products array in subscribe.

```
this.products=[]
data.forEach(el => {
this.products.push(el)
});
```

Comment: Also, can't seem to get this to work unfortunately

Comment: the code block you've just shared is simply doing the same thing with this.products = data;

Answer (score -2):

```
try using:

<label *ngFor="let product of products | async">
    {{ product.id }}
</label>
```

Comment: Gives the following error:
NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
Thanks for the help though

Comment: This won't work since products isn't observable.